# Can not pick random number from Array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have this code and I want to pick a random element from Array1 and a random element from Array2 but Xcode is only giving me the number of the element.

```
let firstNrVar = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
let secondNrVar = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
func numberRandomizer() {
    let shuffledFirstNr = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(firstNrVar.count)))
    firstNrLbl.text = "\(shuffledFirstNr)"
    print(shuffledFirstNr)
    let shuffledSecondNr = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(secondNrVar.count)))
    secondNrLbl.text = "\(shuffledSecondNr)"
    print(shuffledSecondNr)
}
```

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly, you're trying to access the array's value? This would be as easy as
`let firstValue = firstNrVar[shuffledFirstNr]`
Your label would then be set via 
`firstNrLbl.text = "\(firstValue)"`

Currently, you're only getting a random index, not the array's value at that index.

Comment: No, I want it to pick up randomly an element from the Array {firstNrVar}, and another random element from the Array {secondNrVar}.
That's mean the number must be 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 or 10, but xCode is counting where the number is and printing it out.

Comment: Yup, that's what I thought. With your current code, you are generating a random *index*, which you can use to access an array's value at that index.
That you could do as mentioned above.

Comment: *Xcode is only giving...* Xcode has nothing to do with it -- it's your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to get the random index between 0 and array count and then get the value at that random index and then set that value to the text

```
func numberRandomizer() {
  let shuffledFirstIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(firstNrVar.count)))
  firstNrLbl.text = "\(firstNrVar[shuffledFirstIndex])"
  print("\(firstNrVar[shuffledFirstIndex])")
  let shuffledSecondIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(secondNrVar.count)))
  secondNrLbl.text = "\(secondNrVar[shuffledSecondIndex])"
  print("\(secondNrVar[shuffledSecondIndex])")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the values using the number of the element.

```
let value = firstNrVar[shuffledFirstNr]
firstNrLbl.text = "\(value)"

let secondValue = secondNrVar[shuffledSecondNr]
secondNrLbl.text = "\(secondValue)"
```